# In a for loop, how do I echo only the current file on a single(updating) line instead of EVERY file which will produce a list?

Tags: linux, bash, echo

My first question on this stackexchange, and I am sure there will be more as I venture farther into the world of what is Linux...

I have a for-loop in a shell-script that batch renames all files to a substring (the last n characters) of its original name.

It will `echo` every iteration on a new line to eventually produce a list of all files but how do I keep that echo on a single/updating line so it doesn't produce this (sometimes large) list?

```
echo "- Renaming file..."

for file in `find fldr -type f`
do
  newf=$(echo $file | rev | cut -c -6 | rev)
   mv -f $file fldr/$newpt
  echo "  * $file > $newf"
done
```

*actual output...*

```
- Renaming file...
  * file1a.txt > 1a.txt
  * file2a.txt > 2a.txt
  * file3a.txt > 3a.txt
  * ...
```

*desired output...*

```
- Renaming file...
  * file3a.txt > 3a.txt
```

I would like to see the one line always changing to show the current file only.

[BONUS] How would I get it to also display the n'th file it is renaming?

```
- 3 files renamed...
  * file3a.txt > 3a.txt
```

Where n is a cumulative sum/count of the files renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the echo line to this:

```
echo -ne "\r  * $file > $newf                         "
```

The spaces on the end clear old output from the line.

Comment: Umm, I think it should be `echo -ne "\r * $file > $newf           ` Otherwise echo will not interpret escape characters.

Comment: `printf` is more portable when it comes to escape chars: `printf "\r  * %s > %-50s" "$file" "$newf"`

Comment: Worked for me. But sure, printf is probably better, but I just did a simple modification to the original here.

Comment: Thanks! Looks promising. I will get to try it out this afternoon but I can see the logic. Will mark as correct when I get it working.

Comment: @chris You're right, I tried it, and it wouldn't work without the -ne I am doing this is in Bash on Ubuntu 10.04 if that makes any difference...   Thanks for the help all.